# Automatic scroll the page to a div after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollto, scrolltop

I'm new in javascript, now I'm trying to do that, as the title, I've a page which has a div at the top that is as big as the page with a video in it, followed by several sections like this:

```
<div id="first" style="height:100%; width:100%"></div>
<section id="second" style="height:100%; width:100%"></section>
<section id="third" style="height:100%; width:100%"></section>
```

Now I need 5 seconds after the page is loaded to scroll automatically the page to #second.
I've tried many ways but have failed and haven't found nothing that works properly.

Thanks

Comment: `I've tried many ways`, what ways? Show us what you have.

Comment: What happens if the user starts scrolling on his own before 5 seconds has happened? are you going to interrupt his/her scrolling and start your own? that could be annoying.

Comment: generally, scrolling to a particular section after x amount of time will lead to bad user experience since you don't know that the user will do in those 5 seconds. Maybe they don't want to view the video, or they pause the video and started scrolling already only to be taken to the target location after 5 seconds.

Comment: actually maybe it's better with a button..

Answer (score 4):

I'm feeling generous, so I'll just give you the code this time.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    //normally you'd wait for document.ready, but you'd likely to want to wait
    //for images to load in case they reflow the page
    $('body').delay(5000) //wait 5 seconds
        .animate({
            //animate jQuery's custom "scrollTop" style
            //grab the value as the offset of #second from the top of the page
            'scrollTop': $('#second').offset().top
        }, 300); //animate over 300ms, change this to however long you want it to animate for
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this at the end of your codes

```
setTimeout(function(){window.location.hash = '#second';},5000);
```

**Note** that those `height:100%;` are wrong.

Comment: I've tried with something like that..     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mysite.it/js/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    
$(...).scrollTo( #slider, 3000 );

</script> nothing works, obviously

Comment: `setInterval` would repeat indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
window.location.hash = '#second';
```

This will set the focus.  I'll leave you to put in some work on a timer solution.

Also, I would discourage any forcing of the user to focus on a particular div.  This is not a very good UX practice and can lead to chasing users off your site, especially because they may not understand why the page is scrolling up.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    setTimeout(function () { goToSecondTab(); }, 5000);
    function goToSecondTab() {
        window.location.hash = '#second';
    }
});
```

Comment: I've put this in the header but nothing changed..  <script type="text/javascript">
    
$(function(){
   setTimeout(goToSecondTab(), 5000)
   function goToSecondTab(){
    window.location.hash = '#second';
   }
});

</script>

Comment: You have to pass a function to `setTimeout`, not `undefined`

Answer (score -1):

Add HTML to this line in zzzzBov's script to make it work properly in FF:

```
$('html, body').delay(5000) //wait 5 seconds
```